# Error when iterating an RMarkdown using kableExtra::column_spec()

Tags: longtable, pandoc, rmarkdown, tinytex

This is my best shot at a minimum example, but it's still a little long and convoluted.

I've created an RMarkdown that generates a PDF of the cars dataset using Pandoc and LaTeX. I want the width of the second column to be exactly 9cm.

````
---
title: "debug_colWidth"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
        in_header: "header.tex"
params:
  fileName: ''
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, comment=NA)
```

```{r packages, results='hide'}
pckgs <- c('knitr', 'kableExtra', 'tinytex')

for(pckg in pckgs){
  if(!pckg %in% installed.packages()[, 'Package']) {
    install.packages(pckg, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
  }
  require(pckg, character.only=TRUE)
}
```

```{r}
knitr::kable(cars, booktab=TRUE, longtable=TRUE, format="latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::column_spec(2, width="9cm") %>%
  kableExtra::row_spec(seq(1, nrow(cars), 1), hline_after=TRUE)
```
````

Using a wrapper R script called debug_colWidth_run.R, I can iterate the rendering however many times I want, specifying a different output file name for each iteration:

```
pckgs <- c('rmarkdown', "stringr")

for(pckg in pckgs){
  if(!pckg %in% installed.packages()[, 'Package']) {
    install.packages(pckg, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
  }
  suppressMessages(require(pckg, character.only=TRUE))
}

arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
fileNames <- strsplit(arg[1], "|", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]

for (name in fileNames) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    "debug_colWidth.Rmd",
    param = list(fileName=name),
    output_file = paste(name, '.pdf', sep = '')
  )
}
```

So long as I'm in the same directory as the markdown and wrapper script, the bash call goes like this:

```
Rscript "debug_colWidth_run.R" "cars1|cars2"
```

Things run fine on the first iteration and cars1.pdf successfully renders. However, cars2.pdf fails to render from the .tex file output by Pandoc. Error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> r>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash 
                                          }p{9cm}
l.84 ...ble}{r>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{9cm}}
```

Pandoc's output LaTeX line in question is `\begin{longtable}{r>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{9cm}}`. This LaTeX line runs fine on the first iteration, so I have no idea why it would fail on the second. If I comment out the `kableExtra::column_spec()` function call in the original RMarkdown, things run fine too, and I can iterate however many times I want.

In bash, `Rscript "debug_colWidth_run.R" "cars2"` also runs fine. It seems that, for whatever reason, using `column_spec()` to specify the table's column width breaks things ONLY when I try to iterate. Why on earth is this happening?

Here's my header.tex for anyone interested:

```
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: The  real MWE of this error is  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} \arraybackslash hello \end{document}` and you can solve it  adding  `\usepackage{array}` in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed the problem. My distribution of LaTeX, TinyTeX, seems to have been automatically adding `\usepackage{array}` to my .tex preamble so that the error usually would not trigger. This is why I did not recognise this as a package dependency issue.

Maybe the `column_spec()` call in the RMarkdown, which terminates the LaTeX line with `p{9cm}`, prevents TinyTeX from recognising the package dependency when iterating. That's my best guess. Again, thanks for your help.